# Why are there so many users with exactly 101 rep? How much is an up vote worth?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Look like there are hundreds of meta users at exactly 101 reputation. Why is that? And how much is one up vote worth?  Easy Q's.

Comment: relatedly: why does account rep drop to '1' after the first downvote on a new site if you haven't gotten an upvote first?

Comment: @warren - I know that it was a long time ago, but do you have a link to that question? Or has it been deleted? Neither a Search Q&A, nor a google turns up the post.

Comment: @Greenonline - I don't, no .. my guess is it's been deleted. Also, downvoting isn't allowed until a rep of 125 now

Answer (score 28, accepted):

New accounts start with one rep.

Account association for users with over 200 rep on one site gives a 100 point bonus to their account on the new site. That is how you get the 101 rep.

Each upvote is worth 10 points for answers and 5 points for questions as long as your answer or question is not community wiki and you are not over your daily rep limit already.

Comment: What happens if I associated before I had 200 reputation points, and have now? They just dont exist? I think I'm in this exactly situation. :)

Comment: @GmonC - remove your account associations and then reassociate. This will add the 100 points if you have an account with 200+.

Comment: @GmonC - I don;t know how it worked back in 2009, but nowadays 100 points is added to each and every site you [already] belong to, when you reach 200 in one of them.

Answer (score 10):

I think because they migrate their profiles from other sites in the trilogy.  That gives you 100.

Start with 1 + 100 = 101

Answer (score 3):

In the case of meta everybody's SO profile was copied over (which is why a lot of people have the same user id on SO and Meta) to create the initial population of users. Most of these won't have been interested in using meta so they'll have the initial amount of rep which I believe was set to 101 to enable everyone to vote down straight away (**NOTE** this was before the reputation required to vote down was increased to 125). This was later formalised as the 100 point bonus for linking accounts.

New people registering will start at 1 unless they link a 200+ point account from SO, SF or SU.

Comment: Vote down requires 125 reputation.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H - it wasn't always thus and certainly not in September **2009** when I wrote this answer.