# Unknown Reputation Points Source

Tags: discussion, feedback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there so many users with exactly 101 rep? How much is an up vote worth?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23064/why-are-there-so-many-users-with-exactly-101-rep-how-much-is-an-up-vote-worth)

How come some new users got points withOut doing anything ?!

like our Friend here

[image]

so is it a mistake or What Is Going On..?!

Comment: GOD .. everything is duplicate over here..!!!!!!!!

Comment: That's why we have a "search" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#login =>  "You must have an OpenID. If you have a registered account on any other sites in our network with at least 200 reputation, you will receive a +100 point reputation bonus when you first log in."

See also: [Should stack overflow sites share base rep(100) to some degree?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90000/should-stack-overflow-sites-share-base-rep100-to-some-degree)